# Why does the Cars 2 game always start in 3D mode on my PS3?

Tags: ps3, cars-2

I have the Cars 2 video game for the PS3 and it is quite fun.

Unfortunately, every time I start the game, after the video presentation, I get to the main menu and it is automatically in 3D.  I have to navigate to settings and turn 3D mode off.  The game successfully leaves 3D mode, and the screen notes that it is saving settings when I leave the menu.

The next time I turn the game on, it's back in 3D mode.

My TV is an LG 55LW5600, which has 3D capability, and is linked to the PS3.  I do not think I have 3D mode active in the PS3, and I generally do not play in 3D mode.

I would like to fix this so I can let my son have some independence without him calling for daddy to fix the "bad screen" every time.

Anyone else have this problem?  How do we fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem with a lg 47lm620s....some idea to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Turn HDMI to limited in the ps3 system settings

Comment: Why does this fix the issue?